# CSS How to get the same height?

Tags: css

My html:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="main">
<div id="rightmain">
            <h1>asdasdasdasd</h1>
            <h1>asdasdasdasd</h1>
            <h1>asdasdasdasd</h1>
            <h1>asdasdasdasd</h1>
            <h1>asdasdasdasd</h1>
            <h1>asdasdasdasd</h1>

</div>
<div id="leftmain">
    <div style=" background:blue;height:20px;width:190px;border:1px solid black;display:block;">
        <h1>asdasdasdasd</h1>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {position: relative;}
#rightmain { float: right;
    width: 768px;border:1px solid black;}
#leftmain {    position: relative;
    width: 160px;}

#wrap {    position: relative;
    width: 960px;}
```

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/buyC9/51/

How do I get the same eight of the #leftmain div as the #rightmain div?

The height of the #rightmain div varies therefore I a can't define the height to example 400px.

Comment: Simply add a table.Inside table define your divs.

Comment: I have a table in the #rightmain. Don't want a table layout ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the same height for both use the .height() in jQuery.

```
if ($('#leftmain').height() > $('#rightmain').height()) {
    $('#rightmain').height($('$leftmain').height());
} else {
    $('#leftmain').height($('#rightmain').height());
}
```

This way you will always have the same height, even if the left long appears to be longer than the right one.

Answer (score 2):

I think..It's possible with Jquery and more easier like as below 
>

> $(function () {
>
> ```
>         var h = $('#rightmain').height();
>         $('#leftmain').css("height", h);
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table. Or JavaScript.

JS example (using jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    var rightMainHeight = $('#rightmain').height();
    $('#leftmain').height(rightMainHeight);
});
```

Comment: How would you do it with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$('.col').each(function() {
    if($(this).height() > maxHeight ) {
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
    };
});

$('.col').height(maxHeight);
```

Look at this fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/buyC9/51/